# Wordpress site language issue

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress (4.8.2) with a Divi theme (3.0.78) and a WooCommerce (3.1.2). So everything is up to date. When I try to change the site language in the admin panel it doesn't work. I want to go to french language but it stays in English. Although the language option in the DB goes to fr_FR it keeps the site language in English. Does anyone has a clue about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few time for looking it appears that it was a Divi option which was at the origin of the issue. I had to disable the "Disable Translations" in the Divi/Theme Options/General.